# How to use xargs to save environment variables to file

Tags: bash

After reading the man pages, I don't understand how xargs work. How can I use it to save my current environment variables to .bashrc for use later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no obvious way to use `xargs` for this: `xargs` takes lines from standard input and makes each line a separate parameter added to the command given in its invocation. For example:

```
echo -e 1\n2\n3 | xargs RunProg --options
```

will expand to this command:

```
RunProg --options 1 2 3
```

The best way to list your environment variables is:

```
declare -p
```

This output can be written or added to `~/.bashrc`. Note that each variable will be defined by a `declare` statement, which works fine, but is not the syntax you would normally use.

You can use `sed` to massage the output to a more familiar format, and omit any variable types (such as arrays) which you may not want.